# What is the regex for checking string A for the presence of any 3 consecutive characters in string B?

Tags: java, regex

For example:
I have a username string: "johnwatson@221b.bakerstreet"

I want to search some password string to make sure it doesn't contain any 3 consecutive letters in the username, e.g.: no "joh", "ohn", "hnw", etc...

I'm aware of a functional way to do this, but is there a way to do this with regex?

Comment: Although I use a password manager, I prefer to pick passwords I can remember. Every arbitrary rule (must contain one of this set of punctuation characters, must contain a digit... ) makes it that much harder to find a strong but memorable password.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately I don't get to make these rules! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no, you should do this in your application code by generating all the 3-letter substrings and checking if the password contains any of them.

But if you feel adventurous, you could still summon a bloody regex monster from a 19th century gothic novel to achieve this.

See @sln's and @Floris's answers for that.

My 2cents: **that's a very, very bad idea**. Regex are great when you have a *fixed, regular syntactical structure* to recognize, which is not your case.

Comment: +1 for summoning a bloody regex monster from a 19th century gothic novel

Comment: Cool use of "bloody regex monster", but I think you are wrong. As you can see in @sln's answer (or my recasting of that answer into an even simpler form), regex is quite capable of detecting this repetition without a invoking the Ultimate Regex Of Doom.

Comment: Woops, I did not notice that the password and the username are chained in a single string! Well, I think that @sln's answer still qualifies for the Ultimate Regex of Doom. I mean, however clever (wow) it might be, it will sit in the codebase as a magic spell, with very few if any people able to mantain or expand it.

Comment: Agree that sln's solution is obscure; but `(?=(...).*\n.*\1)` is pretty readable, as regexes go. As for "magic spells" - the proper word for "book of magic spells" is "grymoire", and http://www.grymoire.com is a most fascinating place to visit.

Answer (score 1):

Capture 3, consume 1
Taking a guess. Catenate username + newline + password.
(atually not a guess)
Context:  NO Dot-All
If a match, then error.

```
 # johnwatson@221b.bakerstreet\nPassword
 # (?=(...)[^\n]*\n(?:(?!\1).)*\1)


 (?=                # Lookahead assertion start
      ( . . . )          # Capture 3 non-newline chars
      [^\n]* \n          # Get up to and the next newline
      (?:                # Cluster group start
           (?! \1 )           # Backref check, not the current 3 char string in front of us
           .                  # This char is ok, consume it in the assertion context
      )*                 # Cluster group end, do 0 to many times
      \1                 # Here, found a user name sub-string 
                         #   in the password, it will match now
 )                  # Lookahead assertion end
```

Comment: Wizardry! Very clever approach. I have not tested in detail but the approach is very plausible. Not sure about the `.` after the negative lookahead. Can you explain why you need it?

Comment: Hang on, I'll comment it.

Comment: Actually more complicated than I thought. Probably is gonna get false positives, I need to work out the ending, or entire re-work.

Comment: Ok, I think the ending is appropriate. Untested but maybe works.

Comment: Alright, tested in Perl. The engine should auto-bump along (consume)  a single character since its all lookahead. After all, its looking for a match real hard. And, this is simpler and works.

Comment: I believe the following shorter expression works too. Would you care to critique? Totally inspired by your answer... `(?=(...).*?\n.*\1)` .   See http://regex101.com/r/kY8uW2

Comment: Even better. It's easy now.

Comment: Don't need the '?' Though.

Answer (score 1):

Heavily inspired by @sln's answer, I would like to offer the following solution:

First - concatenate your user name and password into a single string, separated by a newline (assuming that newline does not otherwise occur in either user name or password; reasonable assumption, I think).

Next, test the resulting string with the following expression:

```
(?=(...).*\n.*\1)
```

(See it at work [here](http://regex101.com/r/qN9fL4))

How this works:

```
(?=   )    - positive lookahead: "somewhere we can match this"
(...)      - three consecutive characters - 'capture group'. We can refer to these as \1
.*\n       - followed by "anything" up to a newline character
.*\1       - followed by "anything" up to a repeat of the first match (the ...)
```

This is going to try as hard as it can to find a match (that's what regex tries to do). If it succeeds, it means that there was a repeat of three consecutive characters that occurred *before* the `\n` in the part *after* the `\n`.  So try to test for the above; if it succeeds, your "rule" was violated.

**edit - example of complete (tested, working) Java code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class passwordTester
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String username="johnwatson@221bakerstreet.com";
        String password = "youcantmakethisup";
        String input = username + "\n" + password;
        System.out.println("testing " + input);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=(...).*\\n.*\\1)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        if(m.find()) {
          System.out.println("the three character sequence '" + input.substring(m.start(), m.start()+3)+ "' was repeated");
        }
        else System.out.println("the password is good");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
testing johnwatson@221bakerstreet.com
youcantmakethisup
the three character sequence 'ake' was repeated
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Regular expressions don't have "memory" and doing what you want requires memory of previously-matched characters. This might be possible with some of the more evil Perl extensions to regular expressions (inline code?), I'm not sure, but I don't believe this is possible with "pure" regular expressions.

Comment: "regular expressions don't have memory"? What about `\1` etc. "That thing you saw before, that I marked with a capture group".